# Undecidable definition of pure function

Tags: logic, computer-science, formal-languages, recursion, paradoxes

I am trying to come up with a formal definition for functional purity in a simple programming language (think JavaScript). What I've got so far is this:

> **DEFINITION**: A statement is *impure* if
>
> - it is an assignment, unless it assigns to a local variable
> - OR, it evaluates a call to a function, unless that function is pure
> - OR, it is a block containing an impure statement
>
> **DEFINITION**: A function is *pure* if it doesn't contain any impure  statement.

For simplicity, let's ignore *assignments* altogether and assume that a *block* is simply an ordered set of statements. (it shouldn't make a difference)

Now, this definition works great until somebody defines a function that refers to itself, e.g.

```
function fibonacci(n)  {
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

or

```
function f() { return g(); }
function g() { return f(); }
```

Suddenly, the definition becomes undecidable.

Is this a common logical paradox?
How would I modify this definition, so that "by default" a function is considered pure?

Comment: Your question is about computer science rather than mathematics. In mathematics all our functions are as pure as snow and all our recursions are well-founded $\ddot{\smile}$. You will do much better to ask your question on http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think this is really just a logic problem. Trying to define functional purity is how I ran into it, but the fundamental issue seems to be the recursive definition with no way to "escape" it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a computer science question, but as you insist that it is not, let me explain why in an answer: a pure function in a programming language is one whose result is determined solely by the values of its parameters and not by the state of the program when it is called. It is the programming language semantics that define what happens when you call a non-terminating function.

It is unclear whether you intend your definition to be a syntactic condition or a semantic one. If the former then it still "works great" in the presence of loops and recursion, but you have to qualify what it means when the pure function turns out not to terminate. If the latter, then it is already undecidable for while-loops, so recursion isn't introducing a new problem. There is no paradox involved here.

As an aside: [Rice's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem) is something that may interest you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If we ignore the problem of termination for a moment, the issue basically comes down to "to prove that fibonacci() is pure by this definition, you need to prove that fibonacci() is pure" - which is AFAIK undecidable. As we intuitively know that this function indeed is pure, the definition must be flawed. How to escape the loop?

Comment: The issue comes down to "this implementation of fibonacci() is or is not pure in such-a-such a programming language". The notion of a pure function is a programming language concept and not a mathematical one. Please take this question to http://cs.stackexchange.com where it belongs.

Comment: I still don't agree that that's the core of the problem. The predicate could have been "is the function F green?" and the issue would boil down to the same issue with recursiveness.

Comment: The function that maps $n$ to the $n$-th element of the Fibonacci sequence is a mathematical concept: it makes no sense to say that it is "pure" in the sense of a function in a programming language or that it is "green" in some physical sense.

Comment: I could propose a definition of what functions "are green", just as I have proposed a definition of functional purity. I don't see why that doesn't make sense.

Comment: It would not be a property of the mathematical function, it would be a property of the way you have defined the function in some language.